# Handle two big APIs data processing quickly in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading

I am working on spring boot application, in which some data to be processed from another API and reports are created.

I have situation where I have to fetch the data from one API and the process it, from first API I have to extract some data and then call second API to set the result in the object.

It's sequential thing, I have to get the data from first then from first's result second API hit.

```
    public MyOrderPart getReport(**List<FirstAPIResult> serviceOptions**) {

        MyOrderPart myOrderPart = new MyOrderPart();
        List<MyOrderPartObject> myOrderPartList = new LinkedList<>();      
        try {          
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token);
            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
            if (!serviceOptions.isEmpty()) {
                for (MyReportModel myReportModel : serviceOptions) {
                    List<SomePartHeader> partHeaderList = myReportModel.getPartHeaders();
                    for (SomePartHeader partHeader : partHeaderList) {
                        MyOrderPartObject myOrderPartObject = new MyOrderPartObject();
                        myOrderPartObject.setSegmentNo(String.valueOf(myReportModel.getSegmentNo()));
                        myOrderPartObject.setOperationNo(String.valueOf(myReportModel.getOperationNo()));
                        myOrderPartObject.setCompCode(myReportModel.getSmcs().getCompCode());
                        myOrderPartObject.setJobCode(myReportModel.getSmcs().getJobCode());
                        myOrderPartObject.setModCode(myReportModel.getSmcs().getModCode());
                        myOrderPartObject.setDescription(myReportModel.getDescription().getDescription());
                        myOrderPartObject.setPartBeginSn(String.valueOf(partHeader.getPartHeaderBeginSn()));
                        myOrderPartObject.setPartEndSn(String.valueOf(partHeader.getPartHeaderEndSn()));
                        myOrderPartObject.setPartGroupNumber(partHeader.getPartHeaderGroupNumber().trim());
                        Optional<SomeJobPart> jobPart = partHeader.getJobParts()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(x -> partHeader.getPartHeaderGroupNumber()
                                        .trim()
                                        .equals(x.getMasterPart().getPartNumber().trim()))
                                .findAny();
                        if (jobPart.isPresent()) {
                            //Second API
                             String description = getDescriptionFromSecondAPI(jobPart.get().getPartGroupNumber(), entity);
                            myOrderPartObject.setPartDescription(description);
 hashMap.put(jobPart.get().getPartGroupNumber(), workOrderPartObject);
                        } else {
                            myOrderPartObject.setPartDescription("");
                        }                      
                        myOrderPartList.add(myOrderPartObject);

                    }
                }               
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            context.getLogger().info("error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        myOrderPart.setWorkOrderPart(myOrderPartList);      
        return myOrderPart;
    }
```

Here **List serviceOptions** it return from One API and I am processing it.

Now have to call **getDescriptionFromSecondAPI(...)** from first process.

```
 public String getDescriptionFromSecondAPI(String partNumber, HttpEntity<?> entity) {

    String secondURL = SECOND_API_BASE_URL + "?q=" + partNumber + "&sId=constant";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Object> respEntity = null;
    String description = "";
    try {
        respEntity = restTemplate.exchange(secondURL , HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                Object.class
        );
        Object body = respEntity.getBody();
        String name = (String) ((LinkedHashMap) ((ArrayList) ((LinkedHashMap) body).get("abc")).get(0)).get("name");
        if (name != null) {
            description = name.substring(name.indexOf(":") + 1, name.length());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        context.getLogger().info("Exception  : " + ex);
    }
    return description.trim();
}
```

getDescriptionFromSecondAPI(...) this method taking long time to get the result and setPartDescription(here), it taking less han one second to get the data for one partNumber.

How can I improve the performance of the method so that I can get the response quickly and set it. The input depend from first API. How can I improve it.

I tried this as well :

hashMap created at if condition when I am getting jobPart, then after processed it as :

```
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                hashMap.forEach((key, value) ->
                {
                    String description = getDescriptionFromSecondAPI(key.toString(), entity);
                    ((MyOrderPartObject) value).setPartDescription(description);
                });
            });
```

Then also it taking time around 4+ mins to set the complete object. How can I improve the performance in java spring boot.

Comment: You can migrate to Spring Webflux, WebClient and Reactor to implement this in a reactive way, you'll definitely get better performance, but it's a huge change.

Comment: Just want to optimize the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the second API doesn't let you ask for multiple part descriptions, there's nothing really to do here, because you still need to ask for every part separately.

One thing that you could try to see if you gain any performance improvement is to use a pooled connection manager instead of creating a new `RestTemplate` everytime in `getDescriptionFromSecondAPI()`. You said you were using Spring Boot, so you can try to define the following bean in your configuration class (snippet taken from [here](https://medium.com/@nitinvohra/how-to-improve-performance-of-spring-resttemplate-6af37e0a0f33), you might need to modify it slightly to fit your purpose, I don't know what dependencies you have in your project):

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate pooledRestTemplate() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(2000);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2000);

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();

    return new RestTemplateBuilder().rootUri("http://service-b-base-url:8080/")
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        .messageConverters(new StringHttpMessageConverter(), new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
        .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
        .build();
}
```

Inject that RestTemplate into the service in question and see if that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your current usage of the executor service seems to simply use a separate thread to run all requests sequentially (unless I'm really missing some to me hidden feature of hashMap.forEach). You probably want to execute them in parallel. That means your map needs to be created outside of the executor call and you submit each individual retrieval to the executor individually rather than do of them in a single runnable.

something like:

```
  hashMap.forEach((key, value) ->
     executorService.execute(() -> {
            {
                String description = getDescriptionFromSecondAPI(key.toString(), entity);
                ((MyOrderPartObject) value).setPartDescription(description);
            };
        }));
```

(code might not be syntactically correct but should give you the idea; Note that your structures need to be thread safe...)